# Can typescript make .js default export {...} have type definitions and intelliSense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

## Here is the case

foo.js

```
export default {
  name: ...
}
```

## Goal

I want to give foo.js a type definition so when I writing expor default {} I will get a `name` prop suggestion, so how do I achieve that?

Comment: That is what typings are for https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html